# I have a number format exeception error

Tags: java, android, integer, numberformatexception

I received this error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3e+06"" and its preventing my application to run. I am passing an numeric string value to an int and this occurred. Would it be that the numeric is to big for an integer? Could anyone tell me what this means and any solutions for it?

```
        Bundle getAlarmInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
        titleOfAlarm = getAlarmInfo.getString("Title");
        totalTime = getAlarmInfo.getString("totalTime");
```

// Ok so I am trying to get the value of getAlarmInfo.getString("totalTime"); and pass it to total time which is a string

```
        actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds = Integer.parseInt(totalTime);
```

//then I am taking that value and storing it in  actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds
which is a int.

```
  titleTextView.setText(titleOfAlarm);
```

// I then pass that value to CountDownTime which only accepts ints and longs.

```
        countDown = new CountDownTime( actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds, timeInterval);
        countDown.start();
```

Comment: post your code snippet.

Comment: Where is the exception - the first `parseInt` or the second one? What is the value of `totalTime`?

Comment: ok I got the specific values pointed out @TDG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should post some code, but:

1. what value are you parsing ?
2. the fastest way to check if value is too big is parsing it to `Long` type. If it fits you have your answer

// edit

If you need `int` or `long` and you're casting string that is `3e+06` try casting it to BigInt and from it to Integer. Integer can handle value of 3000000 it is not a problem. But it has problem with casting from string so using my way should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` as shown below:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigIntExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String asString = "3e+06";
        BigInteger number = new BigDecimal(asString).toBigInteger();

        System.out.println("The number is : "+number);
    }
}
```

Output:

> The number is : 3000000

Comment: thanks but I need the value to be a integer or long. CountDownTime only accepts longs or ints.

Comment: that's even more easier just do - `int number = new BigDecimal(asString).intValue();`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `BigDecimal intValue()` for *Scientific Notation* of integer like :-

```
int val = new BigDecimal("3e+06").intValue(); // outputs :- 3000000
```

If the `val` is greater that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` , you can use `BigInteger` like:-

```
BigInteger val = new BigDecimal("3e+06").toBigInteger(); // outputs :- 3000000
```